# How to update yum in Fedora

Tags: linux, yum

I am using Fedora 12 and I have Firefox 3.5, but I want to upgrade it to Firefox 5.0 version using `yum`.

However, when I do that it says that no updates are available because my `yum` repository is old.

Can any one help me with how to upgrade it?  I know there is a command `yum upgrade yum`, but can it update my whole repository? I do not want to use that because it is time consuming.

Comment: It doesn't take that long...

Comment: I fixed up the formatting. I don't know if English isn't your first language, but it really helps us read your question if you use sentences, as opposed to run-on.

Answer (score 3):

You can't update your system because Fedora 12 has reached end of life, and hasn't received any new updates since December 2, 2010.  Firefox 5 is only available on the latest version of Fedora, Fedora 15.

The easiest way to upgrade to Fedora 15 is to use `preupgrade`.  [There are instructions that explain how to upgrade using `preupgrade` on the Fedora wiki.](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PreUpgrade)  Your Firefox will be updated to version 5 as part of this process.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, upgrading from Fedora 12 directly to Fedora 15 (or some such large step) will probably not work, you'd have to go one version at a time (and the stepping stones in thes case will also be end-of-life, as Fedora gets updates for 2 versions + 1 month).

If really needed, look at the instructions given on Fedora's page. But it is probably easier to just reinstall in this case.